# Set selected values in select "box" from values in input field

Tags: jquery, html, select, input

I hope this is a fairly simple question, but I haven't been able to find any solution to this. I have a cms system where I upload different things to via regular forms. Relatively basic. When I have uploaded an item I wan't to be able to edit is as well. All this is working. When one adds an item you need to select one or more businesspartner(s) this item is assigned to. This is done with a select (multiple) field, and the value is stored in a input field. Now when I go to edit the item the values are displayed (seperated by comma) in a Input field.

I want to hide this input field and set the values in the select (multiple) field as selected if these values are in the input field.

I hope my simple JSFiddle can clarify it.

http://jsfiddle.net/ovwoaqmo/

```
<form>
<table class="webform" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="CAT_Custom_5">Partner</label>
                <br>
                <select id="CAT_Custom_5" class="cat_dropdown" multiple="" style="width: 200px;" name="CAT_Custom_5">
                    <option value="test1">test1</option>
                    <option value="test2">test2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="CAT_Custom_5">Partner</label>
                <br />
                <input maxlength="4000" name="CAT_Custom_5" id="CAT_Custom_5" class="cat_textbox" value="test1,test2" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="cat_button" value="Submit" id="catcustomcontentbutton" type="submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am aware that the two fields have the same id, and it is basicly because they are the same fields, and maybe this will cause me problems, or maybe this can be a good thing, I am not quite sure.

Any hints or help is much appreciated :)

**UPDATE/EDIT:**

*I think this can fix my problem: 
http://jsfiddle.net/4EVBL/16/
I just need it to seperate the values by comma in the input field. 
Any help for this? :)*

Comment: You can not have two elements with the same id in one HTML document. And what do you need the input field for anyway? A select element with the `multiple` attribute set is perfectly capable of holding multiple selected options at once already; if you want to see them all at the same time, then use the `size` attribute as well.

Comment: Thx CBroe. I am aware of the ID problem, i put in in there to test. The thing is that the values are not visible in the multiple select box, but they are in the input field. I dont need the input field, but is there a way i can get the select "box" to display the values already selected? :)

Comment: _“if you want to see them all at the same time, then use the `size` attribute as well”_ …

Comment: Can you please explain this to me or a link to documentations/demo. Sorry for the newbie questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var array = $('.cat_textbox').val().split(",");
$("#CAT_Custom_5").val(array);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ovwoaqmo/1/)**

Comment: This actually works, but now i have come across another problem. I can add values multiple times. If i can get the select box to display the values that are in custom_5, i dont need to get the values from the input field which are the same values. I know this is quite a mess :) sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi now you can try to this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('#CAT_Custom_5').on('change', function(){
      var some = $(this).val();
        
       
        
        $('#CAT_Custom_6').val(some);
    
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <table class="webform" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="CAT_Custom_5">Partner</label>
                    <br>
                    <select id="CAT_Custom_5" class="cat_dropdown" multiple="" style="width: 200px;" name="CAT_Custom_5">
                        <option value="test1">test1</option>
                        <option value="test2">test2</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="CAT_Custom_6">Partner</label>
                    <br />
                    <input maxlength="4000" name="CAT_Custom_6" id="CAT_Custom_6" class="cat_textbox" value="" type="text">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="cat_button" value="Submit" id="catcustomcontentbutton" type="submit">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: This also works, but the thing is that on load the values selected when the item was added is not visible in the input field because these values are in "custom 5", so i am not able to change it to "custom 6" :) Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: @user2239933 you can not used one ID in multiple tags in single web page .

Comment: I am aware of that. This is why I asked if i just can get the select box to display the values from custom_5 and remove the input field. The thing is that the values must be there, but for some reason the select field will not display these. So it is ok for me not to have the input field. Another solution for me could be to have the select box with another ID, and just use this to "select" the values that are in the input field (custom 5), could this be done, so I just use the select "box" to pass values to the input field, so i am sure that the values are spelled correct etc.? :)